# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I want to display list of customers for that I am writing one services class in that class writing one function **getCustomer()**

**data.service.ts**

```
 //  @Injectable() // comment to this line in service if we are inject service in component
    export class DataService {
    constructor(public http: Http) { }
    getCustomers(): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.customersBaseUrl)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(response => response.json().data as ICustomer[])
                   .catch(this.handleError);
      }
}
```

In **customer.component.ts** call getCustomer()

```
 constructor(@Inject(DataService) private dataService: DataService) { }
 ngOnInit() {
    this.title;
    this.filterText = 'Filter Customers:';
    this.dataService.getCustomers().then(customers => this.customers = customers.slice(1, 5));
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({ 
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CustomersComponent,
    ],
    imports: [ 
        HttpModule,
        app_routing,
        ..     
    ],
    providers: [
     DataService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent,NavbarComponent]
})
```

Give me suggestion if i am wrong in any point.I am new in typescript so I don't have that much idea about this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you declared your service under providers in your ngModule? Possibly in a file called app.module.ts

Comment: yes I already declared service and httpModule in app.module.ts

Comment: for dataService instantiated or not I am giving condition .and in console "find services" meassgae display ..

Comment: Do you have another solution ?

Comment: it looks fine by given code, can you please share app.module and service.ts, I think "http" is undefined here, I don't know what is "@Inject(DataService)" here. did you add decorator "@Injectable()" on service class ???

Comment: yes I am already adding @injectable() on service class.but after that I am adding in component "@Inject(DataService)".If not add it's giving  error  is "Can't resolve all parameter in CustomersComponent(?)" thats why I am adding "@Inject(DataService)"

Comment: Actually I found out exact error..please help me to solve this. Error is in Http is not inject in DataService and which inject in component that's why this error is coming....

Answer (score 1):

just change your code as below..

```
ngOnInit() {
this.title;
this.filterText = 'Filter Customers:';
this.dataService.getCustomers().subscribe(customers => this.customers = customers.slice(1, 5));
```

}

In data.service.ts

```
getCustomers():  Observable<ICustomer[][]> {
    return this.http.get(this.customersBaseUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <ICustomer[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

Comment: subscribe is property of observal and then is property of promise..if change subscribe instead of then. Then it's  give error

Comment: Actuall I found out exact error..please help me to solve this

Comment: Finally , It's working if we are inject service in component then no need to @Injectable() to service i.e DataService..just comment this @injectable() in service file..I will update code

Answer (score 0):

comment to @Injectable() in DataService. if we are inject service in component then no need to inject in service

```
//@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
    constructor(public http: Http) { }
    getCustomers(): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.customersBaseUrl)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(response => response.json().data as ICustomer[])
                   .catch(this.handleError);
      }
}
```